# Why is it true that $S'(t)/S(t) = d log(S(t)) / dt$?

Tags: statistics, derivatives, logarithms

I came across this identity in derivation of the hazard rate in survival analysis.

Comment: Apply the chain rule to differentiate $\log(S(t))$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{\mathrm d \log(t)}{\mathrm d t}=\frac{1}{t}$$

So: (apply the chain rule)

$$\frac{\mathrm d \log(S(t))}{\mathrm d t}=\frac{1}{S(t)}S'(t).$$

Answer (score 0):

To find the derivative of $\log(S(t))$, start by setting it equal to $y$. We can transform $y=\log(S(t))$ into $S(t)=e^y$, by the definition of the natural logarithm. Differentiate both sides:

$$
\begin{align*}
S'(t) &= e^y \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} \\
S'(t) &= e^{\log(S(t))} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} \\
S'(t) &= S(t) \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} \\
\frac{S'(t)}{S(t)} &= \frac{d[\log(S(t))]}{dx}
\end{align*}
$$

as desired.